# how to reinstall civicrm 4.6.4 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation

After dealing with a corrupted wordpress site and **reinstalling wordpress**, i **re-enabled the civicrm plugin** but did not re-install civicrm.

The backend seems to work fine except that **widgets do not work and the Civicrm Page needs to be recreated.**  I tried to re-save the Civicrm page in the CMS integration admin form. Also tried to run the installer /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install but get a message: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

**I suppose I could disable the civicrm plugin, wipe the database, install civicrm and overwrite the database but wondering if there is a more practical solution?**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a better answer but this is what I resorted to:

1. Clear Cache
2. Disable civicrm plugin
3. Delete /templates_c/ contents
4. Copy civicrm database to civicrm.sql using mysqldump and delete all tables (or drop / recreate database)
5. Move /civicrm/civicrm.settings.php tocivicrm.settings.tmp
6. Enable Civicrm Plugin
7. Run Civicrm install script http:///wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install
8. Page Civicrm is created and I presume other civicrm install magic in wordpress
9. Disable civicrm plugin
10. Replace civicrm.setttings.php with civicrm.settings.tmp
11. Restore civicrm mysql dump (e.g. mysql civicrmdb < civicrm.sql)
12. Re-enable civicrm plugin

Answer (score 0):

First Delete your civicrm plugin and files folder. Don't keep anything regard to civicrm delete whatever u have.

And then again upload the civicrm plugin into wordpress.

Again create the files folder in plugin folder

[image]

Right click the files folder and give permission

Comment: Thx but my goal is to reinstall an existing civicrm stack that is fully configured.  Is that what you are suggesting?